# button back navigation bar crash

Tags: iphone

I have a crash when i click in the back bar in the navigation bar, the crash log is :

```
-[__NSCFType hidesBottomBarWhenPushed]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x2f2480
```

what can be the reason of my crash ?

thanks for your answers

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what `NSCFType` is, maybe a Core Foundation placeholder for unknown types. As far as I know it's not documented, but it often shows up as the target of over-released pointers. In other words, you released your `UIViewController` and then tried to read the property `hidesBottomBarWhenPushed`.